# how do I read a long list of data from a file?

Tags: c

I am practicing C with a periodic table project. I have this **.txt** file that contains all the elements in this order:
`atomic_number name symbol mass_number`.

My program was supposed to populate an array of structures with the data (for easy searching).
The problem is my program doesn't go all the way to the last element (atomic_number = 118) it just stops at 54 and doesn't print further. It also does not populate the array beyond 54.

Here is how I have tried to tackle the problem

**file: populate.c**

```
#include "periodic_table.h"

int populate(void)
{
    struct element
    {
        int atomic_num;
        char name[15];
        char symbol[5];
        float mass_num;
    };

    // Array to hold the elements
    struct element e[118];

    // checks that the file exists
    FILE *ptr = fopen("periodic_table.txt", "r");
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("No file to read from.\nExiting...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int line;   // first line of the txt file
    for (line = 1; line <= 118; line++)
    {
        if (fscanf(ptr, "%d %s %s %f", &e[line].atomic_num, &e[line].name, &e[line].symbol, &e[line].mass_num))
        {
            //print is just for debugging purpose
            printf("%d record: %d %s %s %.2f\n", line, e[line].atomic_num, e[line].name, e[line].symbol, e[line].mass_num);
        }
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    fclose(ptr);
    return (0);
}
```

My text file looks like this

```
1 Hydrogen H 1.01
2 Helium He 4.00
3 Lithium Li 6.94
.
.
.
116 Livermorium Lv 293.00
117 Tennesine Ts 294.00
118 Oganesson Og 294.00
```

Comment: 1) Arrays are 0 based in C: `for(line = 1; line <= 118; line++)` -> `for(line = 0; line < 118; line++)` 2) You want `if(fscanf(...) == 4)` 3) `fflush(stdin);` is wrong

Comment: Don't use `&` when scanfing into an array. The array name by itself is already converted to the right address to use ... `scanf("...%s...", ..., e[line].name, ...)`

Comment: Code defensively. Use limits for strings inside scanf: `scanf("...%14s%4s...", ..., e[line].name, e[line].symbol, ...)`

Comment: Along with the other advise, I would suggest reading and printing out each line as a string first to make sure you know what is going on with your data. If any line doesn't match your fscanf specifiers, then it will behave unpredictably. For example I noticed that some atomic masses, online, are listed within brackets, not as decimal numbers, this might cause fscanf to think they are strings.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior. Flushing is meant for the output stream.

Comment: re: error messages.  When `fopen` fails, it does not indicate a failure to read the file, it indicates a failure to open the file.  If a user sees the message "no file to read from" but they see that the file exists, it may cause unnecessary confusion.  Accurate error messages are important, and easy to generate.  And they belong on stderr.  `printf("ERROR ...` is *always* wrong (it should be `fprintf(stderr, "ERROR ...`).  Try `char *name="periodic_table.txt";  if( (ptr = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL ){ perror(name); ...`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell
Thank you so much for pointing out my amateur error handling skills... I really appreciate this

@pmg
Yeah sorry about that, I had the warning on the codeblocks terminal but choose to ignore it. I later removed the `a` when I got tired of seeing the warnings
"code defensively..." got it! Thank you so much for your time

@mgillett
Thank you so much

@Irelia It was completly unnecessary, I was just desperate to try to get it to work LOL

@DavidRanieri Thank you. I appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your program:

- the definition for `struct element` and the array `e` is local to the `populate` function, so the data will be unavailable once the function returns.
- the index variable `line` should run from `0` to `117` as it is used to index the `e[118]` array.  accessing `e[118]` has undefined behavior.
- you should read one line at a time and use `sscanf()` to parse the line, and report conversion errors along with the line contents for easier debugging.
- the test `if (fscanf(...))` is incorrect: the return value should be `4` if all 4 conversions succeeded. any other result should be considered an error.
- `%s` is a risky conversion specifier as `fscanf()` can cause a buffer overflow if the file contents has words longer than expected.
- you should not use `&` for destination variables that are arrays.
- `fflush(stdin);` is useless and actually has undefined behavior.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include "periodic_table.h"

// these definitions should be moved to "periodic_table.h"
struct element {
    int atomic_num;
    char name[15];
    char symbol[5];
    float mass_num;
};

// Array to hold the elements
struct element e[118];

int populate(void) {
    // checks that the file exists
    FILE *ptr = fopen("periodic_table.txt", "r");
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No file to read from.\nExiting...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int line;   // first line of the txt file
    for (line = 0; line < 118; line++) {
        char buffer[128];
        int pos;
        if (!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, ptr)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot read element %d\n", line + 1);
            break;
        }
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%d%14s%4s%f%n", &e[line].atomic_num, e[line].name,
                   e[line].symbol, &e[line].mass_num, &pos) == 4) {
            //print is just for debugging purpose
            printf("%d record: %d %s %s %.2f\n",
                   line + 1, e[line].atomic_num, e[line].name,
                   e[line].symbol, e[line].mass_num);
            if (buffer[pos] != '\n') {
                fprintf(stderr, "line %d: extra data: %s\n", line + 1, buffer + pos);
            }
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "line %d: invalid data: %s\n", line + 1, buffer);
        }
    }

    fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed it.
Thanks to your 
```c
else {
            fprintf(stderr, "line %d: invalid data: %s\n", line + 1, buffer);
        }
```
I found out I made a mistake in line 55. I had `55 Caesium 55 Cs 132.91` which was causing my code to break.

I learnt a lot from this solution. Thanks a bunch